# django.contrib.gis.geos throws segfault

Tags: python, django

Following the example code snippet from the django-documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.Polygon, I get a Segfault when iterating over the LinearRing of a Polygon.

```py
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geos import Polygon, LinearRing
>>> ext_coords = ((0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0))
>>> int_coords = ((0.4, 0.4), (0.4, 0.6), (0.6, 0.6), (0.6, 0.4), (0.4, 0.4))
>>> poly = Polygon(ext_coords, int_coords)
>>> [c for c in poly]
[<LinearRing object at 0x7fa81326d610>, <LinearRing object at 0x7fa81326d810>]
>>> [c for c in poly[0]]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Why does this code throw a segfault? How can I get the code to run?

Originally, I got this error with Python 3.6.7 and Django 3.0.9. I upgraded to Python 3.8.2 in the hope that this is just a compatibility issue between Python 3.6.7 and Django 3.0.9: But upgrading and setting up a new virtualenv did not solve the error.

Since the crash happens when iterating over a LinearRing of a Polygon, I tested if looping through just a LinearRing throws an error:

```py
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geos import Polygon, LinearRing
>>> ext_coords = ((0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0))
>>> int_coords = ((0.4, 0.4), (0.4, 0.6), (0.6, 0.6), (0.6, 0.4), (0.4, 0.4))
>>> ls1 = LinearRing(ext_coords)
>>> ls2 = LinearRing(int_coords)
>>> [c for c in ls1]
[(0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0)]
>>> [c for c in ls2]
[(0.4, 0.4), (0.4, 0.6), (0.6, 0.6), (0.6, 0.4), (0.4, 0.4)]
>>> poly = Polygon(ext_coords, int_coords)
>>> [c for c in poly]
[<LinearRing object at 0x7f84815f6610>, <LinearRing object at 0x7f84815f6a10>]
>>> [c for c in poly[1]]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

As the Example shows, iterating over *just* a LinearRing is possible, but iterating over the LinearRings, when in a Polygon produces a SegFault.

EDIT: I found out that avoid the crash by using the `.coords`-attribute: `[c for c in poly[0].coords]`. But I still don't know, why the original code produces a segfault.

Comment: You should post what worked for you as an answer and accept it. Sadly using `.coords` doesn't work for me.